# Can I replay an AL module with the same character to get a treasure I missed?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, dnd-adventurers-league

I was wondering about the rules on replaying an official D&D 5e Adventurer's League module with the same character:

If I am willing to forgo taking anything with me during the initial session (ie, no xp, rewards, DT days, renown, gold etc), can I run it a second time with the same character?

The reason being that this is the only module in all three seasons that has a weapon my character is able to use, and I'd like a second chance at rolling for it.

Comment: How have you managed to build a 5th ed character who's that limited in weapon selection?

Answer (score 13):

**You can't play the same character through an AL adventure twice.**

> Players can play an adventure they previously played or ran as a DM, but not with the same character.

This restriction appears in the head-matter of Encounters and Expeditions materials. For recent examples, see DDEN3-1 p.3 or DDEX3-1 p.2.